# Cron.php undefined index 'SCRIPT_FILENAME'

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

## Synopsis

I'm getting this error:

> Cron.php undefined index 'SCRIPT_FILENAME'

Why is the following code in the magento core `cron.php`?

```
// Only for urls
// Don't remove this
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = str_replace(basename(__FILE__), 'index.php', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
```

So my crontab has the following (in cPanel - *yes, I hate cPanel but I have no choice*):

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh /home/user/public_html/cron.sh 2>&1
```

When run, I get this output:

```
Array
(
    [MAILTO] => ***
    [SHELL] => /usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell
    [USER] => ***
    [PATH] => /usr/bin:/bin
    [PWD] => /home/***
    [LANG] => en_US.UTF-8
    [HOME] => /home/***
    [SHLVL] => 2
    [LOGNAME] => ***
    [_] => /usr/bin/php
    [PHP_SELF] =>
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1427981401.51
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1427981401


    [argv] => Array
        (
            [0] => /home/***/public_html/cron.php
        )

    [argc] => 1
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As **mam08ixo** has stated certain `_SERVER` properties are available on the CLI, however, due to some abnormal configuration I solved this by using `php-cli`:

```
php-cli /home/***/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null &2>1
```

Answer (score 3):

This is what worked for me:

```
php -f /home/USERNAME/www/cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And I had to modify cron.php, just use

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

instead of

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Reference: http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

I kept getting Undefined index in my error log but it was working. However, to make it better, I initialized the variables in cron.php to remove the errors. Like so:

```
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] = '';
$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'] = '';
```

Answer (score 2):

How come you "ultimately" think that the `$_SERVER` *execution(!) environment information* is not available when running scripts via CLI?

The [PHP language reference](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) contains some hints and comments that it actually does. Also, on any machine in my sphere, `$_SERVER` is populated just fine. So if you get an *undefined index* notice, it's most likely due to some specialties with your environment rather than a general fail in `cron.php`.

Pay special attention to the [`variables_order`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) setting.

Appendix: You might want to regard `$_SERVER` as *information acquired from the serving entity*. May it be shell, mod_php, fastcgi, or whatever. That's why the contents (keys) of the variable depend on the current environment. Bottom line is, `$_SERVER` is NOT only populated when served via webserver.

Comment: I use: `/usr/bin/php -d display_errors=1 -f cron.php` and the errors occur.  Also I have done a test with `print_r($_SERVER)` inside the `cron.php` and the indexes do not exist.

Comment: based on your appendix, that is correct - but why does magento still error with undefined indexes - it's stupid.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is a top result in Google for missing `SCRIPT_FILENAME` with cron I will chime in.

For me, on a different ecom (CS-Cart on cPanel OpenVZ + FastCGI), cron's missing indexes were solved/found by using the path to php in cron instead of just `php` or `php-cli`. Run `which php` in shell or as then use that in cPanel cron builder. I'm theorizing that this may be due to cPanel using its own internal version of PHP, perhaps sprinkled with some FastCGI mysteries, although I'm still not exactly sure.

Examples:

`php /home/account/public_html/script.php` <- Fails

`php-cli /home/account/public_html/script.php` <- Fails

`$(which php) /home/account/public_html/script.php` <- Works in CLI as dynamic route, but will fail in cPanel cron builder

`/usr/local/bin/php /home/account/public_html/script.php` <- Works in cPanel cron builder, although it's a static route to php, so that may be different on your server

Comment: I remember initially having some problems with `$(which php)` when documenting my answer, however this should be useful to others, and generally is what I would use myself normally.  I forgot if it was cPanel or Plesk that caused my problem though.

Comment: @ash Yeah I hear ya about `which php`, especially with the CloudLinux/WHM multi php manager throwing env into other versions. Speaking of stuff others may need, I ran into more cron woes the other day trying to get Vtiger to validate/run correctly under `php-cli`. Made a little helper script that tries to expose more env infos (such as "_" index) if anyone needs for troubleshooting: https://gist.github.com/dhaupin/7c88be87a543e59f5be9fb55c7b963a9

Answer (score 1):

There may be 2 solutions to this particular/system specific issue that I'm aware of:

In the crontab:
Add the following 2 lines at the top of it:

> SCRIPT_NAME="cron.php"
>
> SCRIPT_FILENAME="cron.php"

OR

Wrap it into the CRON itself:

> */5 * * * *  SCRIPT_NAME=cron.php; SCRIPT_FILENAME=cron.php; php ~/public_html/cron.php > /dev/null 2>&1

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me on Godaddy Cpanel:

```
/usr/local/bin/php -q /home/USERNAME/public_html/path_to_cron.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

And I had to modify `cron.php`, just use

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

instead of

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Thank you Zurd for posting your answer which got me mine after soo much pain!!!